# Image sizes - desktop vs. tablet

Tags: image, users, speed

Are there any generally recommended best practices for image size requirements?  Mostly looking at desktop vs. tablet. Is it generally accepted for a a RWD site that a separate set of smaller image should be used for tablet vs. desktop?

Right now, certain landing pages have images as high as 1mb, and a total download of around 4.7mb. Should I be concerned? Once again, only concerned about desktop and tablet. Assumption is that on average, a tablet user will have a slower connection considering slower processing speed, possibility of being on a 3g or lte connection, or connected to wifi.

Here's a link to a sample page for insights. Thanks!

http://demo.thebambergergroup.com/b/1/110-east-36th-street/murray-hill/nyc

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any generally recommended best practices for image size
>   requirements?

No.

> Is it generally accepted for a a RWD site that a separate set of smaller image should be used for tablet vs. desktop?

In most cases, yes.

> Right now, certain landing pages have images as high as 1mb, and a total download of around 4.7mb. Should I be concerned?

Absolutely! The larger the image size, the slower the download and the slower the browser can work with such large files/images. You **must** optimize them! Mobile visitors will give up on a site such as yours. Not to mention how search engines feel about a slow loading site (and Google hates that).

Now, I say you must and that is a "generally recommended practice". The exceptions depend on your content. If you are fashion photography site, I presume your visitors want high resolution images but you are concerned about mobile users so you need alternate images to serve for mobile networks.

How much of a difference can this make? I just converted your image of the inside of one of those rooms from 180K to 36K file size with no loss of quality, sized for the image size on that page.

Answer (score -1):

Most tablets have higher resolution screens than the average desktop and laptop screens, and are much closer to the user's eyes. So you will have to use better images, not lesser ones, to create a good impression with tablet users.

The most common Tablet resolution is 2048x1536, the most common desktop resolution is probably 1920x1080.

The most common laptop resolution is probably slightly less.

Comment: Thanks-- i'm a bit confused by tablet resolution-- specifically ipad and ipad mini. My understanding is that render at half the full resolution. So, if my site is using RWD, what size should images be so they render well on all desktop sizes and tablets? Should I implement a max width of 2048 so that ipad users have a great experience? what are common practices? I'm mostly concerned about loading time as image resolution increases. Are there any articles pointing to how this should be done? Many thanks

Comment: Probably articles about it. RWD is mostly a scam. You have to think about the users and design for them, and then use something that makes sure each device gets the best option. Well, for popular devices in influential markets. Like the iPads. They're both 2048 screens, small and big iPad.

Comment: Just use the same site graphics you're using for desktop, and make sure it scales nicely for the iPad's 4:3 aspect ratio and size.

Comment: Don't worry about data, users are mostly smart enough to be sure to be on WIFI when browsing big heavy sites.

Comment: wifi connections can still be slow @Confused

Comment: @Gasper And some cars still have low power engines, manual gearboxes, slipping clutches and leaky head gaskets.